# realmDb initialization error

Tags: android, realm

I heard about RealmDb which is a convinient database that can replace sqlite on android platform.

im trying to get it working on my galaxy s2 android version 2.3

i use realm version 0.79.1

however i get the following massage:

```
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:199)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:516)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:480)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:397)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:359)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:340)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.project.peoples.PersonListActivity.addTestPersons(PersonListActivity.java:134)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.project.peoples.PersonListActivity.onCreate(PersonListActivity.java:34)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load tightdb-jni: findLibrary returned null
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.internal.TightDB.loadLibrary(TightDB.java:144)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<clinit>(SharedGroup.java:34)
03-06 12:26:24.820: E/AndroidRuntime(17507):    ... 21 more
```

the cause is the following line:

```
Realm realmDb=Realm.getInstance(this);
```

does anyone knows the cause and how to solve it (i found the folowing but didnt quite understand if it has anything to do with me as i dont use Gson at all
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/620)

update: i have the native libraries inside the libs directory

[image]

**update**
i cahnged the location of the native .so files directories to be direcetlly under the libs directory, that i think solved the earlier problem but presented the following error code:

```
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.mishnayot/com.project.peoples.PersonListActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the initTable method in the generated io.realm.PersonRealmProxy class: Annotation processor may not have been executed.
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552): Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the initTable method in the generated io.realm.PersonRealmProxy class: Annotation processor may not have been executed.
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:591)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:523)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:480)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:397)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:359)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:340)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at com.project.peoples.PersonListActivity.addTestPersons(PersonListActivity.java:134)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at com.project.peoples.PersonListActivity.onCreate(PersonListActivity.java:34)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-06 14:18:18.520: E/AndroidRuntime(20552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm cannot find the native libraries for some reason. Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse. If you are using Eclipse, note that some extra setup is required as described here: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/#getting-started

Comment: i realized that but i followed all the steps and the library does reside inside the libraries (updated question with an image)

Comment: it seems the native libs should reside directlly in the libs directory and not in libs/lib, anyway after doing that i encounter another error massage - updated the question

Comment: It sounds like you are running into this bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/870, we are working on a fix.